# express.js res.sendFile Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: express

I have following code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {  
    // res.sendfile(__dirname + '/forms.html');
    try {
        // serve html snapshot
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/forms.html');
    } catch (err) {
        // no snapshot available, serve 404 error
        res.send(404);
    } 
    return next();
});
```

But at running come following error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at SendStream.headersAlreadySent (/local/home/admin-gst/web/test/lza/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:326:13)
    at SendStream.send (/local/home/admin-gst/web/test/lza/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:525:17)
    at onstat (/local/home/admin-gst/web/test/lza/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:624:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing. Please post the complete code

Answer (score 2):

Since your app.use doesn't specify a route, it is being invoked on every request. If the route being hit also tries to send a response (which I assume is what's happening here based on the error), e.g.

```
app.get('/someRoute', function(req, res) {res.send('success');});
```

you'll get this error because the response was already sent in your middleware.

You'll either need to do res.sendFile in your route rather than your middleware, or conditionally call next() only if the middleware doesn't send a response so that execution stops at the middleware.

Comment: Yes, you have right. But my problem is how can I integrate a form in my middleware and when the form is submitted I want automatically go to the next middleware.

Comment: That's not the question you asked. You should close this question and post a new question with more detail on what you're trying to accomplish.